# Which plants are of type "weed" in the Garden?

Tags: cookie-clicker

Some soils types affect "weeds" like Wood Chips that says weeds appear 10 times less or Fertilizer with 20% more. I am trying to select the best soil type to get Meddleweed to mutate.

So my question is, does "weed" include only Meddleweed or also some of its mutations?

The wikia talks about "plants", "weed" and "fungus" but does not specify exactly which plants correspond to each clasification.

Answer (score 1):

The Wiki doesn't have a subsection dedicated to weeds but it does have a section dedicated to *Fungi*, meaning that there is not enough weeds in the game to put into a list.

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/CookieClicker/comments/88o3hn/guide_for_gardening_on_20055_beta_wip/) reddit post:

> Currently there is only one type of weed: Meddleweed

So the Wood Chips effect is only referencing Meddleweed.

Comment: Crumbspore and Doughshroom are contaminable but also are in the Fungi section you mention, so I guess Weed Growth does not refer to them. The reddit is probably right

Comment: @achecopar Yes most likely. I'll remove it. Wasn't sure if I should add it or not in the first place because I don't play the game.